# How are the pods kube-apiserver,etcd-kmaster,kube-controller and scheduler re-created after deleting them though they are not part of deployment

Tags: kubernetes, replicaset

Following is the basic k8 setup deployed using kubeadm tool. when I delete pods like etcd,api-server,sheduler and controller it re-created immediately. I am wodering who is really monitoring these pods as these are not part of replicaset or deployments and these are  just stand alone pods.

```
root@kmaster:~# oc get all -n kube-system <br/>
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
pod/calico-kube-controllers-7659fb8886-jfnfq   1/1     Running   7 (120m ago)    3d18h
pod/calico-node-7xkvm                          1/1     Running   1 (3d7h ago)    3d18h
pod/calico-node-q8l4d                          1/1     Running   54 (120m ago)   3d18h
pod/calico-node-v698m                          1/1     Running   51 (119m ago)   3d18h
pod/coredns-78fcd69978-ftmwz                   1/1     Running   7 (120m ago)    3d18h
pod/coredns-78fcd69978-kg9r5                   1/1     Running   7 (120m ago)    3d18h
pod/etcd-kmaster                               1/1     Running   7 (120m ago)    3d18h
pod/kube-apiserver-kmaster                     1/1     Running   7 (120m ago)    3d18h
pod/kube-controller-manager-kmaster            1/1     Running   7 (120m ago)    44m
pod/kube-proxy-jcl8n                           1/1     Running   1 (3d7h ago)    3d18h
pod/kube-proxy-tg8x9                           1/1     Running   7 (120m ago)    3d18h
pod/kube-proxy-x58b8                           1/1     Running   7 (119m ago)    3d18h
pod/kube-scheduler-kmaster                     1/1     Running   7 (120m ago)    3d18h

NAME               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
service/kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   3d18h

NAME                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
daemonset.apps/calico-node   3         3         2       3            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   3d18h
daemonset.apps/kube-proxy    3         3         2       3            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   3d18h

NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers   1/1     1            1           3d18h
deployment.apps/coredns                   2/2     2            2           3d18h

NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-7659fb8886   1         1         1       3d18h
replicaset.apps/coredns-78fcd69978                   2         2         2       3d18h
root@kmaster:~#
```

Answer (score 2):

These pods are typically supervised by the Kubelet, directly on the node.

> Static Pods are always bound to one Kubelet on a specific node. The main use for static Pods is to run a self-hosted control plane: in other words, using the kubelet to supervise the individual control plane components.

See [Static Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#static-pods).

Answer (score 1):

To extend the answer of Jonas a little bit:

Kubernetes can manage applications that are core components of Kubernetes such as the `kube-apiserver`, `kube-scheduler` and so on.
On every node [`kubelet` runs as a systemd service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/).

One job that Kubelet has, is to regularly check the folder `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` on every master/control-plane node and run any Pods that are defined in there. These Pods are referred to as [static-pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#static-pods).

If you wanted to you could create your own static-pod by creating a new file on the node:

```sh
$ cat <<EOF >/etc/kubernetes/manifests/my-static-pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-static-pod
  labels:
    foo: bar
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
EOF
```

After a short while Kubelet will run your Pod in the same way as the Kubernetes components.

Since they are managed by Kubelet you actually **cannot** delete them by executing something like `kubectl delete pod >some-static-pod>`. The reason is that all `kubectl` commands go to the `kube-apiserver`. However, static-pods are special in the way that they are **not managed by the Kubernetes API** but by Kubelet itself. `kubectl delete pod <some-static-pod>` may *appear* to delete the desired Pod but that is not the case. The Pod still continues to run on the node.

To delete a static-pod the file on the node needs to be removed:

```sh
$ rm /etc/kubernetes/manifests/my-static-pod.yaml
```